# Subtract 2 hex files line by line in python

Tags: python

Have 2 files with hex values

**file1.txt**

```
0x42528566923Bd44c
0x55A5c6564546b54d
0x3266CD6565e566aa
```

**file2.txt**

```
0x3256AA323ab
0x669bbbb544c
0xa2545bcca55
```

using python i am trying to subtract line 1 of file1.txt from line 1 of file2.txt and so on. My codes

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f1:
    line1 = f1.readline().strip()

          
def key1(line1):
    x = int(line1, 16)
    return (x)
      
      

with open("file2.txt", "r") as f2:
    line2 = f2.readline().strip()

    
def key2(line2):
    y = int(line2, 16)
    return (y)
    
def add(f1, f2):
    P = key1(line1)
    Q = key2(line2)
    R = P - Q
    hx = hex(R).zfill(10)
    print(hx+"\n")
    

add(f1, f2)
```

but I am only able to get first line subtract value, not getting all 3 lines value.

Comment: `readline()` will only reads the first line in the file. You need to add a loop and use`readlines()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with: `line1 = f1.readline().strip()` and `line2 = f2.readline().strip()`. Since you are reading the first line only from each files, you have a single result. You need to do it for all the lines, not just the first one.

Read all the lines, and strip each of them:

```py
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f1:
    line1 = [line.strip() for line in f1.readlines()]
with open("file2.txt", "r") as f2:
    line2 = [line.strip() for line in f2.readlines()]
```

Now, modify the `add` function signature:

```py
def add(line1, line2):
    P = key1(line1)
    Q = key2(line2)
    R = P - Q
    hx = hex(R).zfill(10)
    print(hx+"\n")
```

The `key1` and `key2` functions are fine, so they don't need to be modified.

Now, call `add` for each pair of lines from the files, iterating them parallely with `zip`:

```py
for i,j in zip(line1, line2):
    add(i, j)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
0x425282412798b0a1
0x55a5bfec898b6101
0x3266c34020289c55
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

Hello, the key here is `readlines()` (not official documentation but interesting https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/).
Thus, your code modified can be:

```
def key1(line1):
    x = int(line1, 16)
    return (x)
          
def key2(line2):
    y = int(line2, 16)
    return (y)
    
def add(f1, f2):
    file1 = open(f1, 'r')
    file2 = open(f2, 'r')
    lines1 = file1.readlines()
    lines2 = file2.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines1)):
        P = key1(lines1[i])
        Q = key2(lines2[i])
        R = P - Q
        hx = hex(R).zfill(10)
        print(hx+"\n")
    file1.close()
    file2.close()

add("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
```

**Improvements**

This code works if both files have exactly the same amount of lines, it does not handle any exceptions, that's up to you :)